# SQL server Select variables showing NULL

Tags: sql-server, variables, fetch

in the code below when I run it in Degug mode I can see the variables contain values, however when I select them they show NULL, any ideas? I need to eventually do an Update back to the table [dbo].[HistData]
with the values where RecordID = some number. Any ideas welcome.

```
-- Declare the variables to store the values returned by FETCH.
DECLARE @HD_TckrPercent     decimal(6,3)    --  H2 in above formula
DECLARE @HD_CloseLater      decimal(9,2)     --  F2 in above formula
DECLARE @HD_CloseEarlier    decimal(9,2) --  F3 in above formula
DECLARE @RowsNeeded         INT
DECLARE @RecordCOUNT        INT
SET @RowsNeeded = 2
set @RecordCOUNT = 0        -- to initialize it

DECLARE stocks_cursor CURSOR FOR

SELECT top (@RowsNeeded) [TCKR%], [Stock_Close]  FROM [dbo].[HistData]
ORDER BY [RecordID]

OPEN stocks_cursor

-- Perform the first fetch and store the values in variables.
-- Note: The variables are in the same order as the columns
-- in the SELECT statement. 

-- Check @@FETCH_STATUS to see if there are any more rows to fetch.
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

   -- Concatenate and display the current values in the variables.
   -- This is executed as long as the previous fetch succeeds.
   set @RecordCOUNT = (@RecordCOUNT + 1)
   Print  @HD_CloseLater
IF @RecordCOUNT = 1 
   BEGIN
        FETCH NEXT FROM stocks_cursor
        INTO @HD_TckrPercent, @HD_CloseLater
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        FETCH NEXT FROM stocks_cursor
        INTO @HD_TckrPercent, @HD_CloseEarlier
    END

   Select  @HD_TckrPercent
   Select @HD_CloseLater
   Select @HD_CloseEarlier 

END

CLOSE stocks_cursor
DEALLOCATE stocks_cursor
GO
```

Comment: what do you mean "when you run it in Debug mode"?

Comment: Also, what version of SQL Server?